# Unable to print string (Xamarin Android)

Tags: xamarin.android, eddystone

```
//Beacon MAC Address
string B1 = "E9:32:C6:D9:91:A6";
string B2 = "FA:46:4D:77:C9:9B";
string B3 = "E7:6D:97:D4:83:14";

//Testing
string MAC1;
string Telemetry;
string test;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Create beacon manager
    beaconManager = new BeaconManager(this);

    //Connect to beacon manager to start scanning
    beaconManager.Connect(this);

    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    Button Scan = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Scan);
    TextView B_Name = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.B_Name);
    TextView B_Rssi = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.B_Rssi);
    TextView B_MacAddress = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.B_MacAddress);

    TextView Check = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Check);

    Scan.Click += Scan_Click;

    int num1 = 0;

    eddystone = new Eddystone[3];

    //Create an ArrayList
    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();

    // Wearables will be triggered when nearables are found
    beaconManager.Eddystone += (sender, e) =>
    {
        ActionBar.Subtitle = string.Format("Found {0} eddystones.", e.Eddystones.Count);

        B_MacAddress.Text = "MAC Address " + e.Eddystones[0].MacAddress;
        B_Rssi.Text = "Rssi " + e.Eddystones[0].Rssi;

        e.Eddystones.CopyTo(eddystone, num1);
        arrayList.Add(e.Eddystones[0].MacAddress);
        MAC1 = "Lol";
    };
    Check.Text = MAC1 + " jasdh";
}
```

I need some help with my code.

Currently, I have defined a string called `MAC1`. However, I defined it inside `beaconManager.Eddystone` then tried to display it out. It did not work. It only displays `jasdh`.

I do not understand why. Can anyone tell me the reason?

Answer (score 0):

You're not seeing the text in the variable MAC1 because you set the textview Check to "jasdh". In the code provided you aren't actually updating the Check textview in the beaconManager.Eddystone block. Set the Check text to what ever you want in that code block the same way you do below with Check.Text =